# Laravel 5.1 How to build forgot password functionality

Tags: laravel, passwords, laravel-5.1, forgot-password

I am using laravel 5.1 and I do not know how I should built in the functionality that a user can reset his / her password.

Typing the mail address and getting a route to reset and submit a new password.

I could not find a good tutorial for this purpose so I ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [laravel authentication - reset password](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords) feature for that. The document is self-explanatory.

Comment: ok that worked, do you know how to make a custom validation? Currently it expects an email if I want to reset

Comment: Nevermind I change the validation inside of the ResetsPassword and it worked, but I am not sure if the correct way of doing this

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner. Since it is a small validation rule you its fine to define it there. But if you find yourself adding more validations there, its better to exact them to the Model or you could create a validation request. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#validation-quickstart